# Multiple subclass hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop, subclassing

I have the class hierarchy:

```
class AbstractProcess
{
    virtual void Do() = 0;
};

class BuildProcess : public AbstractProcess
{
    virtual void Do();
};

class UpdateProcess : public AbstractProcess
{
    virtual void Do();
};
```

However, I now want to introduce 2 (4?) new subclasses as a process can also be manual or automated. The following looks to be too long winded:

```
class ManualBuildProcess : public BuildProcess
{
    virtual void Do();
};

class ManualUpdateProcess : public UpdateProcess
{
    virtual void Do();
};

class AutomatedBuildProcess : public BuildProcess
{
    virtual void Do();
};

class AutomatedUpdateProcess : public UpdateProcess
{
    virtual void Do();
};
```

This will only get worse if I want to introduce additional subclasses of either Build/Update or Manual/Automated processes.

Is there a better design?

Comment: C++ supports multiple inheritance, so you could have another base class that handles common functionality for manual work, and one to handle common functionality for automated work. It will mean more classes, but it could also mean better abstractions, as well as less code in the leaf classes.

Comment: Does introducing Manual/Automated processes make former classes abstract? I mean, do you still want to use poor `BuildProcess` w/o specifying if it's manual or automated?

Comment: Andy T - yes, that's a very good point. The Manual and Automated subclasses would now become abstract.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two approaches.

One is to make your `Manual...Process` templated:

```
template<class Process> class ManualProcess: public Process {
    virtual void Do() {
        ...
        // you can access base class data:
        Process::Do();
    }
};

// use like
ManualProcess<BuildProcess> process; // instead of ManualBuildProcess
```

Secondly, have two hierarchies and prefer composition over inheritance, something like

```
class Operator;
class ManualOperator: public Operator...
class AutomaticOperator: public Operator...

class Process {
    Operator* operator;
    ...
};
class BuildProcess: public Process...
class UpdateProcess: public Process...
...
```

or vice-versa (`Operator` holding a pointer to a `Process`), or even in a symmetrical way with `Operator`s and `Process`es not knowing about each other, but with a third class holding a pointer to `Operator` and a pointer to `Process`.

Of course, this all applies only if there is some code common for all `Manual` cases and some code common for all `Build` cases, etc. If each of these version have its own code, then you obviously have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows multiple inheritance. This may make the class hierarchy better, but with such little context it's hard to say what's best.

But you may think of having an AutomatedProcess and ManualProcess directly as subclasses from the AbstractProccess, just as the Build Process and UpdateProcess.

However if all combinations do exist, then you would have to make a class for each one of them, still resulting in the amount of classes you have now.

You may want to think what an automated/manual process does.
It may not need to be a separate class, but it could be a member of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I would minimise inheritance here and use composition. `Manual`/`Automated` is one plane, `Build`/`Update` is another. Seems like your `Process` needs strategies defined in both planes. This can be done as:

```
struct Executor;
struct Operator;

template <typename ExecutorT, typename OperatorT>
struct Process
{
    std::unique_ptr<Executor> executor_;
    std::unique_ptr<Operator> operator_;

    Process():
        executor_(new ExecutorT()),
        operator_(new OperatorT())
    {}

    void Do()
    {
        executor_->Do();
        operator_->Do();
        // do something else
    }
};
```

The rest is pretty simple and now you can concentrate on your business logic:

```
struct Executor
{
    virtual void Do() = 0;
};

struct Manual : Executor
{
    virtual void Do() override {}
};

struct Automated : Executor
{
    virtual void Do() override {}
};

struct Operator
{
    virtual void Do() = 0;
};

struct Build : Operator
{
    virtual void Do() override {}
};

struct Update : Operator
{
    virtual void Do() override {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from vaious object oriented approaches like e.g. [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), you could alo use Templates in C++:

```
template <typename Action> class Process {
    Action a;
    public:
        Process(const Action& action): a{action} {};
        void do() { a.do(); };
};

template <typename Interface> class BuildAction {
    Interface i;
    public:
        BuildAction(const Interface& interface): i{intreface} {};
        BuildAction(const BuildAction& other): i{other.i} {};
        void do() { i.build(); };
};

template <typename Interface> class UpdateAction {
    Interface i;
    public:
        UpdateAction(const Interface& interface): i{intreface} {};
        UpdateAction(const UpdateAction& other): i{other.i} {};
        void do() { i.update(); };
};

class ManualInterface {
    public:
        void build();
        void update();
};

class AutomaticInterface {
    public:
        void build();
        void update();
};

typedef Process<BuildAction<ManualInterface>>     ManualBuildProcess;
typedef Process<BuildAction<AutomaticInterface>>  AutomaticBuildProcess;
typedef Process<UpdateAction<ManualInterface>>    ManualUpdateProcess;
typedef Process<UpdateAction<AutomaticInterface>> AutomaticUpdateProcess;
```

I might have some suboptimal Assumptions for your actual Usecase. You might find better structures like e.g.:

```
typedef Process<BuildAction, ManualInterface> ManualBuildProcess;
```

Of course you can combine templates with OO-patterns as well:

```
Process<ManualInterface> myManualBuildProcess{BuildStrategy{}};
```

BTW.: I have used C++11 syntax. In case you only have C++98, you'll have to adapt the code accordingly.